# Django run scheduled jobs hourly

Tags: python, django, cron

In my project I have to load data in database hourly .I tried celery and cron but found all the stuff very complicated and always createes some issue.I use pycharm in windows. I am new to django and just need a simple solution to run the following command hourly.

This loads data in dabase.

"python manage.py fetchfiles"

```
management/commands/fetchfiles

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from dashboard.models import airdata as tdata
import requests
import json

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Fetches api data'

    """def add_arguments(self, parser):
        none"""


    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        #for a in range(0,1578,10):
        a = True
        offno = 0
        lst2=[]
        dict1={}
        while a == True:
            api_key = "579b464db66ec23bdd000001cdd3946e44ce4aad7209ff7b23ac571b"
            url = "https://api.data.gov.in/resource/3b01bcb8-0b14-4abf-b6f2-c1bfd384ba69?api-key={}&format=json&offset={}&limit=10".format(api_key,offno)
            response = requests.get(url)
            data = response.text
            a1=json.loads(data)
            for ele in a1['records']:
                if ele['pollutant_min'] == 'NA':
                    dict1['pol_min'] = 0
                else:
                    dict1['pol_min'] = int(ele['pollutant_min'])
                if ele['pollutant_max'] == 'NA':
                    dict1['pol_max'] = 0
                else:
                    dict1['pol_max'] = int(ele['pollutant_max'])
                if ele['pollutant_avg'] == 'NA':
                    dict1['pol_avg'] = 0
                else:
                    dict1['pol_avg'] = int(ele['pollutant_avg'])
                dict1['state'] = ele['state']
                dict1['city'] = ele['city']
                dict1['station'] = ele['station']
                dict1['time_vector'] = ele['last_update']
                lst2.append(dict1.copy())
            if a1["count"] < 10:
                a= False
            offno += 10
        airx = json.dumps(lst2, indent=1)
        tdata.objects.bulk_create([tdata(**vals) for vals in lst2])
        return airx
```

Comment: Side note: I guess you should not post API keys in the internet

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways

1. Adding it to crontab on Unix systems or scheduled task on Windows.
2. Using Celery Beat

Answer (score 0):

Celery is probably more complex than you need just to run something like his hourly. You've already discovered writing management commands. Just wrap the management command in a shell script and (on Unix/Linux) get cron to run it hourly. You need to make sure that the shell script stays "quiet" when it succeeds, but makes any failures very apparent so it's not sitting there failing with nobody noticing.

Can't advise what to do on Windows, but I think it has task scheduling.